# "php artisan myCommand" handling the post-install-cmd event returned with error code 1

Tags: php, laravel, console, composer-php, command

I creaded a console command that will setup the database automatically based on user input and I added that command in `post-install-cmd` but when i run the `composer install` command it return `error code 1`.

If i run the command manually like `php artisan setupDB` it work, I dont know what is the issue.

May be I am adding my command in wrong script event!

This is my script section of `composer.json` file.

```
"scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan setupDb",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    }
```

This is the error SS.

[image]

Comment: If you downvote my question, atleast comment a reason.

Comment: I assume you've read [this part](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan#writing-commands) of the documentation? Why are you messing with composer.json? Show us what your `routes/console.php` looks like. And if you say only the `inspire` command exists, then you need to create your own commands properly.

Comment: I downvoted because the question isn't very clear. You need to provide more details to help us understand the problem. As I said, you need to include your console routes; and we need to see where `setupDb` command is created. I also voted to close this question on that same ground.

Comment: Again you don't need to see my setupDb command because it's create in default console folder in app and no need to define that command in console route.   It is an artisan command run like ```php artisan setupDb```. Check full question with composer script and screenshot. All the information are there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the composer version, becase if you run any artisan command in `post-install-cmd` or `pre-install-cmd` it will run but some command ask input from user, just like mine as I describe in question that `setupDb` will take input from user.

### How I found the issue ?

I used an example of `post-autoload-dump` that
`"Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",` was added in this event, I was thinking that for console command there should be something like this.

I try to add `Illuminate\Console` in `post-install-cmd` before artisan command and it return that it is deprecated with current composer version, So i updated my composer to v2, then it work like a charm.

### Answer

So the answer will be that you need to update composer version to run `post-install-cmd` custom commands like(setupDb)

```
"scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan setupDb",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    }
```

and it will not return any error also it will ask input from user if any command require.